# jqplot baselinewidth won't go under 3 px

Tags: css, jqplot

I'm using jqplot to draw some small bar graphs.

However, I'm having trouble with the axis. I need to make them very thin and black to make them fit in with the rest of the styling on the site. But for some reason when I get below about 3px, the axis cease to get any thinner and instead start to turn a lighter and lighter grey.

If I leave as 'null' or undefined it seems the default is 1px but a lighter than black shade as well.

I'm guessing I need to alter something in the plugin itself but I've no idea where to change it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it goes too thin the only option to make it thinner is to work on the rendered color and not size.